# Issues with C# and Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm new in C# and I don't understand how to fix the bugs

> 'jostik' does not contain a definition for 'Horizontal'
>
> 'jostik' does not contain a definition for 'Vertical'

Here is my code

````cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using UnityEngine;

public class jostik : MonoBehaviour
{

    public jostik Jostik;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    float run;
    bool jump = true;




    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();  
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        run = jostik.Horizontal * 5f;

        if(jostik.Vertical >= .5f & jump)
        {
            jump = false;
            rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            rb.AddForce(transform.up * 7.5f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }


        //разгон
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(run, rb.velocity.y);
    }
}```
````

Comment: English please.

Comment: Thank you for asking, there is a lot wrong with your code. First off all make sure you are naming your class right [naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines). Second you are trying to read Horizontal and Vertical from jostik which is the class your in now and and I think you mean the instance of the class ifso MonoBehaviour doesnt contain a Horizontal or Vertical [Unit MonoBehaviour](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) I suggest to do more research like watching/reading tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Since "jostik" is a user defined you got to define class horizontal and vertical

I guess you're confused with this

```
 Input.GetAxis("Vertical")
```